# BI Dashboard (Tableau, Qlikview esque) for Ethereum/Quorum?

Tags: etherscan, quorum

Most of the ethereum transaction explorers (etherscan) I have encountered does not have snazzy analytics capabilities. For enterprise, there is a need to analyse (sum, count, etc) the data in the transaction object.

Is there a BI analytics dashboard for ethereum/quorum?

Comment: Did you figure out any tool yet ?